# Php Waterfall / Gantt chart to indicate date / time

Tags: php, charts

Is it possible to create a Waterfall chart or Gantt chart as a .png from a dataset in php without using commercial plugins? I have searched but found no solutions, any examples appreciated. Gantt chart examples only show dates - I need the time indicated too.

I want to create a chart based on dates, eg:

user 1 start date/time,
user 1 end date/time,
user 2 start date/time,
user 2 end date/time,

Comment: In theory you can do anything whithout plugins, in practice they can save you a lot of time and money

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like d3.js is what you need for this, it isn't commercial but Open Source under a custom licence (but permissive).

There are plenty of examples online using this but one specifically that suits yours is [Gantt-Chart](https://github.com/dk8996/Gantt-Chart)